# Twilio programmable chat: Is there a way to listen to messageAdded event on invited channels?

Tags: php, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I have a list of subscribed and invited channels for a user and I added messageAdded event on client so that it can listen to all the channels (subscribed). Now the need is that I want the user to be able to see new message notifications on the channels where the user is invited but hasn't joined yet.

Is there a way to do it?

PS: This requirement arised 'coz there's a chat channel limit per user and we can add only limited users to the chat channel or have to constantly remove the members from a channel.

Thanks.